# 1D Convolutional network with keras, error on input size

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm trying to build a convolutional neural network for my dataset. My training dataset has 1209 examples of 800 features each.

Here's what part of the code looks like :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='linear', input_shape=(1209, 800)))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss=loss_type, optimizer=optimizer_type, metrics=[metrics_type])
model.fit(X, Y, validation_data=(X2,Y2),epochs = nb_epochs, 
batch_size = batch_size,shuffle=True)
```

When I compile this code, I get the following error :

```
Error when checking input: expected conv1d_25_input to have 3 dimensions, 
but got array with shape (1209, 800)
```

So I add a dimension, here's what I do :

```
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
X2 = np.expand_dims(X2, axis=0)
```

And then I get this error :

```
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. 
Found 1 input samples and 1209 target samples.
```

My training data has now a shape like this (1, 1209, 800), should it be something else ?

Thanks a lot for reading this.

Comment: What is your `Y.shape`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko it's (1209,1), as in i have 1209 examples in the dataset, with only one output each. I tried changing it with 

     Y = np.expand_dims(Y, axis=0)
     Y2 = np.expand_dims(Y2, axis=0)

But it didn't help sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of expanding the dimensions on `X` at axis 0, you should expand on axis 2. Thus, rather than `X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)`, you need `X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=2)`.

Afterwards, the shape of `X` should be (1209, 800, 1), and you should then specify `input_shape=(800, 1)` in your first layer.

Comment: Thanks for answering @blackHoleDetector .
When I specify this input_shape, I get the following error :
    ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_27: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: @VincentBrisse thanks for the update. I just updated my answer. Give it a shot. I believe this will get you working.

Comment: Great to hear @VincentBrisse! I have several Keras videos on YouTube you may find helpful (more being added almost daily). Convolutional neural networks and fine-tuning are the next topics that will be released if you're interested.  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4Huog4qcFfGrq_y7vKMJvg